# Windows Forms method Form.ShowDialog() strange behaviour

Tags: winforms, showdialog

I was trying to show a form(`FormChild`), with some radio buttons in, just to select, close, and get the value of the selected radio button from the calling form(`FormParent`). On a click event handler for a Button in `FormParent`, I just did:

```
var formChild=newFormChild();
formChild.ShowDialog(this);
```

All was working great until I decided to handle the CheckedChanged event of one of the RadioButtons inside FormChild:

```
private void SomeRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}
```

Now the `formChild.ShowDialog(this);` did not showed formChild and formChild immediately returns `DialogResult.Cancel`.

Any explanation on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should set DialogResult() instead of using Close().  Furthermore, you should do that from a Button handler so that the user has the opportunity to change their answer.  What if they click the wrong RadioButton?...the form will imediately close as soon as they make a selection and they won't have an opportunity to change it.

Comment: @Idle_Mind, thanks for your comment, not only that but, indeed I am using now two buttons (Ok, and Cancel) and they are the AcceptButton and CancelButton of FormChild. But my question was specifically under those initial circumstances. Also, now I am just handling the Click event of OkButton, and doing: var rButton = MyGroupBox.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked); Close();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lowest Tab Index radiobutton will  be checked by default, If this event handler is assigned to that button it will cause the situation that you are describing.

You can either change your Tab Order or create a Boolean Flag that is set in your Forms Shown EventHandler to keep it from Triggering until you check it again.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool initDone;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (initDone)
        {
            if (((RadioButton)sender).Checked == true)
            {
                Close();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        initDone = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there anywhere if your code that sets the value of the RadioButton?  If you programmatically set the "Checked" property of the RadioButton, it will fire the event.

In your situation, the event handler contains your Form.Close() so the form never gets the chance to be visible to the user.

Note: Setting the RadioButton.Checked as "true" in the designer will not fire the event.